# JS create custom object with self as parameter

Tags: javascript, object, parameters

I want to pass along "myEvent" through to "myFunction" at the end but in the object "Event", "myEvent" is undefined.

```
var myEvent = new Event(window,"click",myFunction,myEvent);

Event = function(target,type,func,parameter){
    console.log(parameter)                         //undefined
    var eventFunction = function(){
        func(parameter)
    }
    this.delete = function(){
        target.removeEventListener(type,eventFunction)
    }
    target.addEventListener(type,eventFunction);
}
myFunction(parameter){
    console.log(parameter);                  // says undefined but I want the object "myEvent"
}
```

Sry for bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `var that = this` inside Constructor root level, then `func(that)` inside `eventFunction`. No need to explicitly pass along a reference to the newly created object, its already there in your constructor function.

If u need to explicitly pass along the `myEvent` reference, do:

```
var wrapper = {myEvent: {}};
wrapper.myEvent = new Event(...,wrapper.myEvent);
```

Comment: Yes, I know this solution, but in another event the parameter I want to send along may be another variable like a string or int

Comment: `myEvent` has no value at the time your `new Event` is executed. If u need to explicitly state it, I recommend you use a pre-initialized object and declare your new Event as a property of this object. See my updated answer.